# Unable to get any transactions from walletd JSON RPC response

Tags: daemon, transaction-data, rpc, block-explorer

I apologise for being slightly off-topic here, but I'm clueless at this moment and struggling with finding an answer for some time now...

I have daemons forked from original [CryptoNote source code](https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote) and I have no [additional ForkNote methods](http://forknote.net/documentation/daemon/json-rpc-api/) available in daemon. I am running both `coin daemon` and `walletd` on some remote machine and trying to use JSON RPC commands to read the blockchain and store blocks and transactions into database. However, when I send the [`getTransactions()`](https://wiki.bytecoin.org/wiki/Get_transactions_-_Bytecoin_RPC_Wallet_API) request to `walletd` I always see `transactions` as an empty array in response for literally every single block in the blockchain. For example (running command on remote machine):

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8070/json_rpc -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"method":"getTransactions","params":{"firstBlockIndex":90007,"blockCount":1}}'
```

responds with:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "blockHash": "732b37e627eb81f2a49ed340b2e2619bf5fd1fa37ad60d82845bb7388b1cfe23",
        "transactions": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Needless to say, there ARE transactions in that block, which, to make it even more interesting, I can prove by sending the same request to same daemons running on my own computer:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "blockHash": "732b37e627eb81f2a49ed340b2e2619bf5fd1fa37ad60d82845bb7388b1cfe23",
        "transactions": [
          {
            "amount": 9057237,
            "blockIndex": 90007,
            "extra": "013d8a389f5430ebc07622fa2bc456caa05b7e9be8610b4b41ee0569821b4e21aa0208000000000a4f2dbc",
            "fee": 0,
            "isBase": true,
            "paymentId": "",
            "state": 0,
            "timestamp": 1518193326,
            "transactionHash": "30de50736c4f8c5bf77430090fa7928cc886865cc83a3ce59bc723026a0c2a2d",
            "transfers": [
              {
                "address": "XP1JoKorjgT7ifXK3M5yLEQH2nRtNWvUUwc1YHpeeD4ZESb1kD7wLLAKYExoEcAbDjnA6vxZQ5zzKohfNhnxHmr2qaL6HTUEq",
                "amount": 9057237,
                "type": 0
              }
            ],
            "unlockTime": 90021
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wonder why is this happening? I am running both daemons on both machines in a same way, with same flags and ports defined. I'm sure that all ports are opened and I can actually verify that blockchain is in sync and has peers connected on remote machine by requesting [`getStatus()`](https://wiki.bytecoin.org/wiki/Get_status_-_Bytecoin_RPC_Wallet_API):

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8070/json_rpc -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"method":"getStatus","params":{}}'
```

response:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "blockCount": 94061,
    "knownBlockCount": 94061,
    "lastBlockHash": "5ec49e2a4201f1c3cad8fc79a2abec8a794d8fd24136962cb83af8781ed584dc",
    "peerCount": 23
  }
}
```

similar to the response from my local machine...

Am I misunderstanding the basic usage of all this? Is there any other way to use JSON RPC besides `walletd` JSON RPC API to get transactions info? How is it even possible that those 2 machines, with fully synced blockchain respond with different data for the same block?

Comment: Note that there were no transactions in [block 90007](https://xmrchain.net/block/90007) apart from the coinbase transaction.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I wasn’t clear enough, but this is not Monero blockchain, it’s some other coin based on original Cryponote repo... Since this is daemon related problem I thought someone here might know something about this technical-related issue...